# Why SQL Server Kerberos authentication does not work?

Tags: sql-server, kerberos, spn

I am trying to find out why there is no Kerberos authentication on my SQL instance :

```
SELECT COUNT (auth_scheme) as nb, auth_scheme --net_transport, client_net_address 
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
GROUP BY auth_scheme
```

> nb    auth_scheme
>
> 2 (Unknown)
>
> 151   NTLM
>
> 4 SQL

Using KerberosConfigurationManager, requiered SPNs seems to be correctly and automatically registered:

[image]

Here's the error log regarding the SPN for the instance :

[image]

Could you provide ideas to investigate why there is no Kerberos authentication?

All the conditions list at [this Microsoft Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/cc280745(v=sql.105)) have been met.

EDIT :

Cannot add the output because this is confidential info, but the instance is correctly registered :

> MSSQLSvc/hostname.domainName.fr:instanceName

Comment: Are the clients connecting from a remote host using host name that matches the SPN?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I have no idea David, I am only working on the database side. maybe i could put in place a profiler trace in order to get more details ?